# launching iPhone application with watch extension

Tags: iphone, xcode, apple-watch

I have an iPhone application and later added support for Apple Watch (extension and watch). Now when i try to run the application from Xcode 7.1, it always launch watch application simulator and does not run iPhone application. I would like to do the other way round. When i press run/debug, xcode should launch iPhone app in simulator. Is there any way i can do this? or just disable apple watch application to run in simulator. (I have already tried disabling apple watch simulator by going to Hardware > External display > disable, but that does not help )

any guidance will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run iPhone app by changing the **active scheme** to your iphone version.

This picture illustrate what i am saying to select from active schemes

[image]

**And finally it should look like**

[image]

Hope it helps....!!!

Comment: though this is not the exact solution with xcode 7.1, but it did give me the hint to fix the issue. On Xcode 7.1, we see two schemes one with iPhone 6s + 38mm watch and iPhone 6s plus + 42mm watch. I still did modify the app scheme and launch the iPhone app on start instead of watch app. To do so, go to your project scheme, edit, on left select "Run" and on right update executable to your iphone app.